# Learning how to parse strings and use structs in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, struct

I'm trying to mess around with structs and pointers in C. 
What I want to accomplish is for the user to enter a date in the format DD-MM-YYYY in the main(), then to parse the string formatted_date. I've read a few suggestions on how to do this but don't understand how to apply it. Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
#ifndef DATE_H_
#define DATE_H_

// Define the structure date.
typedef struct {
    int tm_mday;
    int tm_month; 
    int tm_year;
} date;

// Parses a string 'formatted_date' representing a date
// in format DD-MM-YYYY, DD.MM.YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY
// into a structure date 'parsed_date'.
void parse_formatted_date(char * formatted_date, date * parsed_date) {

}
```

Comment: You're basically asking for a completely worked-out example of what you're trying to do, along with a step-by-step explanation of what and how it does what it does. That's not how this works. Show us what _you_ have tried first, and tell us _what you've read_. You're not even showing us how you're _calling_ this function, so your `date *` could be a pointer to a stack var, or a heap pointer..., or a null pointer, in which case your function won't work

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sscanf()` to parse this formated date string like this:

```
int parse_formatted_date(const char *formatted_date, date *parsed_date) {
    const int ret = sscanf(formatted_date, "%d-%d-%d",
            &parsed_date->tm_mday,
            &parsed_date->tm_month,
            &parsed_date->tm_year);
    return ret == 3;
}
```

---

Here is the full test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int tm_mday;
    int tm_month; 
    int tm_year;
} date;

int parse_formatted_date(const char *formatted_date, date *parsed_date) {
    const int ret = sscanf(formatted_date, "%d-%d-%d",
            &parsed_date->tm_mday,
            &parsed_date->tm_month,
            &parsed_date->tm_year);
    return ret == 3;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    date d;

    char *formatted_date = "06-03-2014";
    if (parse_formatted_date(formatted_date, &d))
        printf("date: %s\ndd = %d, mm = %d, yy = %d\n", formatted_date,
                d.tm_mday, d.tm_month, d.tm_year);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Gaaah for the `if(bool expression) return true; else return false;` horror. Just saying.

Comment: @unwind Agreed, that format is ugly. Updated, this one should be better.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is better. Best (imo) would be the simplest: `return sscanf(...) == 3;`. Also, if using a temporary, it should be `const`. :)

Comment: @unwind That `?:` is indeed unnecessary. But `return sscanf(...) == 3;` could also be quite hard to be indented to look good. BTW, do you mean `ret` should be `const int`?

Comment: Yes, I mean `const int ret = sscanf(...);`, it should be `const` since it's not intended to be altered after being given its initial value. I don't see the indent problem at all, but I guess this is veering off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot... So this will separate the inputted date into three different strings? In my main, would I be able to replace where you put char *formatted_date with a user inputted date? Although how would I do this when using scanf as it wouldn't be scanf(%d).. would I use scanf(%s)? I understand this is a basic question, just trying to fully understand what I'm doing. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3306583 1. That `sscaf()` will extract three integers from `formated_date`. 2. Yes, you can replace `formated_date` with user inputted date string. 3. Do what? Could you be more specific?